# How can I assign value from string to array inside if statment?

Tags: java

How can I assign value from string to array inside if statment. When I use for loop I'm getting null value. In this program user enters number of boxes then its get substracted from max. This is what I have been working so far. Thanks

```
    System.out.println("Enter the number of boxes");
    boxes[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    i++;


    for(l = 0;l < boxes.length;l++) {

    calcBoxes = boxes[l];

    number = maxBoxes - calcBoxes;

        for(m = 0; m < strangeBox.length;m++){

        if (number >=1 && number <=33){
            trikDescription = "Rabbit";
            numberDesc[m]= trikDescription;
            m++;


        }
        else if(number >=34 && number <=66) {
            trikDescription = "Tired lion";
            numberDesc[m]= trikDescription;
            m++;

    }
        else if(number >=67 && number <=88) {
            trikDescription = "Pink Zebra";
            numberDesc[m]= trikDescription;
            m++;
    }
        else if (number >=89 && number <=100) {
            trikDescription = "Drunk Monkey";
            numberDesc[m]= trikDescription;
            m++;
    }
        else if(number >100) {
            trikDescription = "Simba";  
            numberDesc[m]= trikDescription;
            m++;

    }

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

There's too much code missing to accurately pinpoint what's wrong

> value from string to array inside if statment

What value are you talking about? Which if statement? What array?

`calcBoxes = boxes[l];

```
number = maxBoxes - calcBoxes;

    for(m = 0; m < strangeBox.length;m++)`
```

Where does the variable 'calcBoxes', 'maxBoxes' and 'strangeBox' even come from?
Are you declaring your variables?

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of boxes");
boxes[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
i++;
```

Is this supposed to be in a loop? Why do you 'i++'